# How I fix save the lines traced in a canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to save each stroke of the canvas, but some points are not saved and in some drawings points are lost, as if I draw a flower.

The string that is formed is saved as:
number of points,
coordinate points (x, y).
For each line, all stored in hexadecimal so that they have the same length, in this example maximum number 255, that is FF.

Ex: no_points xy xy xy no_points xy xy xy

03 f4bf f4be f5bd 03 .....

"translated" 3 244 191 244 190 245 189

3 would be the points and other coordinates

[CODE ON JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/qocipic/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
    var flag = false,
        prevX = 0,
        currX = 0,
        prevY = 0,
        currY = 0,
        dot_flag = false;

    var color = "black",
        line_width = 1;

    var current_signature = 0,
        total_lines = [0,0],
        str_lines = [[],[]];

    function init() {
        canvases = document.getElementsByClassName('canvassign');
        ctxs = [];
        w = canvases[0].width;
        h = canvases[0].height;
        for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { //canvases.length just for test
            ctxs[i] = canvases[i].getContext('2d');
            loadSignature(i);
            canvases[i].addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
                findxy('move', e)
            }, false);
            canvases[i].addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
                findxy('down', e)
            }, false);
            canvases[i].addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
                findxy('up', e)
            }, false);
            canvases[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
                findxy('out', e)
            }, false);
        }
    }

    function findxy(res, e) {
        if (res == 'down') {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvases[current_signature].offsetLeft;
            currY = e.clientY - canvases[current_signature].offsetTop;

            flag = true;
            dot_flag = true;
            if (dot_flag) {
                ctxs[current_signature].beginPath();
                ctxs[current_signature].fillStyle = color;
                ctxs[current_signature].fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
                ctxs[current_signature].closePath();
                saveDot(current_signature,currX,currY);
                dot_flag = false;
            }
        }
        if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
            flag = false;
                saveLine(current_signature);
        }
        if (res == 'move') {
            if (flag) {
                prevX = currX;
                prevY = currY;
                currX = e.clientX - canvases[current_signature].offsetLeft;
                currY = e.clientY - canvases[current_signature].offsetTop;
                draw();
            }
        }
    }

    function draw() {
        ctxs[current_signature].beginPath();
        ctxs[current_signature].moveTo(prevX, prevY);
        ctxs[current_signature].lineTo(currX, currY);
        ctxs[current_signature].strokeStyle = color;
        ctxs[current_signature].lineWidth = line_width;
        ctxs[current_signature].stroke();
        ctxs[current_signature].closePath();

        str_lines[current_signature].push( [currX, currY] );
    }

    function getSignature(n_signature) {
        str_points = document.getElementById("signature"+(n_signature+1)).value 
        if(str_points==""){
            return;
        }
        cutToLines(n_signature, str_points)
    }

    function cutToLines(n_signature, str_points){ //coordenadas coordinates
        chars = 2;
        full_length = str_points.length;
        str_index = 0;
        while (str_index < full_length) {
            total_points_hex = str_points.slice(str_index, str_index+chars);
            total_points = toDec(total_points_hex)
            real_total_points = total_points*4;
            begin = str_index+chars;
            end = real_total_points+begin;
            line = str_points.slice(begin, end);
            drawLines(line, total_points, n_signature);
            //console.log("-----");
            str_index = end;
        }
    }

    function splitEvery (s, interval) {
        var result = [];
        if (typeof s !== 'undefined'){
            for (var i=0; i<s.length; i+=interval)
                result.push(s.substring (i, i+interval));
        }
        return result;
    }

    function drawLines(line, total_points, n_signature) {
        // console.log("drawing Lines(line: "+line+" "+"total_points"+total_points+"n_signature "+n_signature);;
        n = splitEvery(line, 4)

        xy = splitEvery(n[0], 2);
        // console.log("x2:"+xy[0]);
        // console.log("y2:"+xy[1]);
        x2 = toDec(xy[0]);
        y2 = toDec(xy[1]);

        if(n.length!=total_points){ //this is for testing, delete this
            total_points = n.length; 
            console.error("total_points no match with the length");
        }
        if (total_points==1) {
            // console.log(xy[0]+xy[1]); this for debug
            ctxs[n_signature].beginPath();
            ctxs[n_signature].fillStyle = color;
            ctxs[n_signature].fillRect(x2, y2, 2, 2);
            ctxs[n_signature].closePath();
            // console.log("dot");
        }

        for (var i = 1; i < total_points - 1; i++) { //check -1
            x1 = x2;
            y1 = y2;
            xy = splitEvery(n[i], 2);

            // console.log(xy[0]+xy[1]);
            x2 = toDec(xy[0]);
            y2 = toDec(xy[1]);

            ctxs[n_signature].beginPath();
            ctxs[n_signature].moveTo(x1, y1);
            ctxs[n_signature].lineTo(x2, y2);
            ctxs[n_signature].strokeStyle = color;
            ctxs[n_signature].lineWidth = line_width;
            ctxs[n_signature].stroke();
            ctxs[n_signature].closePath();
        }
    }

    function toHex(s){
        var a = s.toString(16);
        if ((a.length % 2) > 0)
            a = "0" + a;
        return a;
    }

    function toDec(s) {
        var a = parseInt(s, 16).toString(10);
        a = parseInt(a, 10);
        return a;
    }

    function changeSignature(selected_signature, not_selected) {
        current_signature = selected_signature;
        document.getElementById("canvas_sign"+(not_selected+1)).style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("canvas_sign"+(selected_signature+1)).style.display = "inline";
    }

    function clearSignature() {
        ctxs[current_signature].clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        ctxs[2].clearRect(0, 0, w, h); //just for test
        document.getElementById("signature"+(current_signature+1)).value = ''
        str_lines[current_signature] = [];
        total_lines[current_signature] = 0;
        console.clear();
    }

    function save(){
        var form = document.getElementById('test_form');
        form.submit();
    }

    function saveDot(n_signature, x, y) {
        //console.log(n_signature) problems wear with n signature, uncomment this
        // console.log("saving dot")
        // console.log(x+" "+y)
        total_points = 0;
        points = '';
        xy = toHex(x) + toHex(y);
        if(xy.length!=4 && xy.length>0){
            // console.error(xy);
        }else{
            // console.log(xy)
            total_points++;
            points = points + xy;
            savePoint(n_signature, total_points, points);
        }
    }

    function savePoint(n_signature, total_points, points){
        console.log("drawlines"+total_points);
        drawLines(points, total_points, 2); //just for test
        if(total_points>0 && points!==''){
            txtsignature = document.getElementById("signature"+(n_signature+1))
            txtsignature.value = txtsignature.value + toHex(total_points)+points; //str_lines[n_signature];
            str_lines[n_signature] = [];
        }

    }

    function saveLine(n_signature) {
        if(n_signature!=2){ //for test
            total_lines[n_signature] = 0;
            total_lines[n_signature] = str_lines[n_signature].length;
            var points = '';
            total_points = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < total_lines[n_signature]; i++) {
                point = str_lines[n_signature][i];
                var [x, y] = point;
                xy = toHex(x) + toHex(y);
                if(xy.length!=4){
                    // console.error(xy);
                    continue;
                }
                // console.log(xy)
                total_points++;
                points = points + xy;
                //console.log(points);
            }
            savePoint(n_signature, total_points, points);
        }
    }

    function loadSignature(n_signature){
        if(document.getElementById("signature"+(n_signature+1)).value!=='')
            getSignature(n_signature);
    }
    init();
```

Sometimes it works sometimes not
I am thinking that sometimes if I only make one line I do not make it complete, as it cuts the last part, that is what I think happens in more complex drawings.

Example:
[drawing example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJASC.png)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g081f.png)

Comment: Code on [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/qocipic/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach clearly has a problem when one coordinate gets bigger than 255 because those numbers when converted to hexadecimal require more than two digits.

Comment: I don't need to save coordinates greater than 255 for now, in fact it has a patch